# How to archive all photos from an album in google photos app

Tags: google-photos

I have an album with more than thousand photos in it. I want to archive all the photos in this album. I didn’t see any option in google photos app for archiving all the photos inside an album.

Is there any way to do it quickly without having to select all the photos one by one and then archiving.

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: No. I didn't found solution to this yet

Answer (score 2):

I put all the photos in an album, then from the landing page I performed a search, keyword [album_name]. Search returned the same number of photos as is in the album, but I haven't checked them one by one. Then, select all and select archive.

Comment: only problem with this approach is that i am finding it sometimes takes more than a week after uploading and creating and album that it will actually find it in a search, which is, quite frankly, ludicrous!

Answer (score 0):

I've only found a way to do it from the desktop app :

- click the checkbox to select the first photo
- scroll to the end of the album
- hold shift and check the checkbox on the last photo

It should check everything, and then you can archive them with one click.

I had no luck googling for this exact question until I thought to search for "Select All" instead of "Archive All".